# How to Connect my android app with Raspberry pi 3

Tags: windows-iot, android

I am making smart door lock system using raspberry pi 3 the door will open through android app I have confusion about how can i make connection of my android app with raspberry pi using WIFI.

Comment: You connect your Android app (in a phone, I suppose) to the Pi using the Pi's IP address. For example, [you could use the `ssh` protocol to connect to the Pi](https://itsfoss.com/ssh-into-raspberry/) and run a bash or python script that opens the door.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.